# :active does not work in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

The :active code works in all browsers, **except IE8** (not 9).  I've looked at other similar questions to this and have tried different methods.  This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main" style="color:white;font-family:Georgia">
   <div id="button" onmouseup="someFunction()"></div>
   <!-- other things -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button
{
  position: relative;
  width: 241px;
  height: 41px;
  background-image:url("images/buttonStatic.png");
  display: none;
}

#button:hover
{
  background-image:url("images/buttonHover.png");
}

#button:active
{
  background-image:url("images/buttonActive.png");
}
```

The button displays proper, changes to the second button when I hover over it properly, but doesn't change to the third button when I click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this out in IE8 and it works fine. Make sure your DOCTYPE specification is declared correctly `<!doctype html>` and maybe try putting in the IE compatibility meta tag which is something like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`.

On a side note, you shouldn't be using a `<DIV>` element as a button like that. You should use `<button>` or `<a>` with suppressed behaviour.

### Edit

Here's my code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
        <title>Active Button</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.5.0/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css&3.5.0/build/cssfonts/cssfonts-min.css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button {
                padding: 4px 12px;
                border: solid #555 1px;
                background-color: #ddd;
                }
            .button:hover {
                background-color: #eee;
                }
            .button:active {
                background-color: #09c;
                color: #fff;
                }

            .frame {
                padding: 2em;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="frame">
            <button class="button">I'm a Button</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Brendan, that meta tag worked perfectly!  All of the company computers run IE8 still, so that not only fixed that problem, but made some other CSS elements function more properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it's a known bug (sorry, discrepancy) in IE8.

Comment: Really? A quick search shows you commenting on this issue previously:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9
http://doctype.com/active-state-ie8
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769392/a-with-an-inner-span-not-triggering-active-state-in-ie-8
http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/9110-ie8-active-problem/

I can post more but you get the idea. In-house, we don't bother fixing IE's issue with it anymore (it's simply eye candy and not worth the hassle), but if you absolutely have to have it in older versions jquery will save the day:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057861/how-to-make-active-state-work-in-ie