# :active being ignored by IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm making custom buttons with images and then using a `div` to align the numbers where I want them.

This method is working in every browser but IE. The text centers on the buttons but it is floating to the top. When I click on the button it completely ignores the `:active` for the button so all that is happening is the `.numKeypad:active` is working but the button does not.

What to change to make it work in IE? This is the part of my code I think is relevant:

HTML

```
<div id="btn1" class="btnKeypad" onclick="input(1);">
    <div id="num1" class="numKeypad">1</div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#btn1 {
    background-image: url(../images/btnUp.png);
    cursor:pointer;
    left:129px;
    top:63px;
}

#btn1:active {
    background-image: url(../images/btnDown.png);
    left:129px;
    top:63px;
}

.numKeypad {
    bottom:2px;
    font-size:20pt;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
}

.numKeypad:active {
    bottom:0px;
    font-size:18pt;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
}
```

Comment: try finding an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9

Answer (score 2):

These threads might help you out:

[How to make :active state work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057861/how-to-make-active-state-work-in-ie)

[:active css selector not working for IE8 and IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9)

[<a> with an inner <span> not triggering :active state in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769392/a-with-an-inner-span-not-triggering-active-state-in-ie-8)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

A tip regarding the CSS. This should do the exact same job without having unnecessary extra lines of code.

```
#btn1 {
background-image: url(../images/btnUp.png);
cursor:pointer;
left:129px;
top:63px;
}

#btn1:active {
background-image: url(../images/btnDown.png);
}

.numKeypad {
bottom:2px;
font-size:20pt;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
}

.numKeypad:active {
bottom:0px;
font-size:18pt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know what I'll be doing the rest of the day.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clean up the code a little, forgot I don't need anything else unless I'm changing something.

Answer (score 0):

Found the best solution, had to change things up a bit.

new HTML

```
<div id="btn1" class="btnKeypad" onclick="input(1);">1</div>
```

new CSS

```
#btn1 {
    background-image: url(../images/btnUp.png);
    cursor:pointer;
    left:129px;
    top:63px;
}

#btn1:active {
    background-image: url(../images/btnDown.png);
}

.btnKeypad {
    font-family:'Old Standard TT', serif;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:36px;
    font-size:20pt;
    z-index:100;
    height:36px;
    width:42px;  
}

.btnKeypad:active {  
    line-height:37px;
    font-size:18pt;
}
```

I still have an issue with the text aligning at the top of the button only in IE but the functionality now works on everything exactly the way I designed it to. I moved everything into one div and condensed it. Now to see about using a different CSS for internet explorer to get the text to align. Thanks to user3687283 for helping clean the code up a little.